# XSLT adding extra <br> tag when "copy-of" is used

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xml-namespaces, line-breaks

I am transforming this XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<song xmlns="http://openlyrics.info/namespace/2009/song" version="0.8" createdIn="OpenLP 2.0.1" modifiedIn="OpenLP 2.0.1" modifiedDate="2012-03-14T02:21:52">
  <properties>
    <titles>
      <title>Amazing Grace</title>
    </titles>
    <authors>
      <author>John Newton</author>
    </authors>
  </properties>
  <lyrics>
    <verse name="v1">
      <lines>Amazing grace, how sweet the sound<br/>That saved a wretch like me<br/>I once was lost, but now am found<br/>Was blind but now I see</lines>
    </verse>
```

with this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:o="http://openlyrics.info/namespace/2009/song">
<xsl:output method="html" />
<xsl:template match="o:song">
<html>
<body>
<h2><xsl:value-of select="o:properties/o:titles/o:title"/><br /></h2>
<h3><xsl:for-each select="o:properties/o:authors/o:author">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/><br />
  </xsl:for-each></h3>
  <xsl:for-each select="o:lyrics/o:verse/o:lines">
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
```

Each part of the "lines" has a br/ tag I want to keep, which is why I'm using copy-of instead of value-of. This is what I'm trying to get from "lines":

```
<lines xmlns="http://openlyrics.info/namespace/2009/song">Amazing grace, how sweet the sound<br/>That saved a wretch like me
```

Instead, the XSLT changes the br/ tag into

```
<br></br>
```

and yields two line breaks instead of just the one I want.

```
<lines xmlns="http://openlyrics.info/namespace/2009/song">Amazing grace, how sweet the sound<br></br>
```

Is there a way to prevent this br/ transformation and preserve the br/ tags present in the XML while still using copy-of? What am I doing wrong here?

Note: Strangely, when I delete the namespace in the "song" tag and write the XSLT as if there were no namespaces, such as

```
  <xsl:for-each select="lyrics/verse/lines">
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
```

then I don't have this problem. The br/ tags are preserved. So I feel like it has something to do with using the namespace.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is probably not a feature of the XSLT itself, but of the way the XSLT is being run on the XML, and how the output is serialized. How are you running the XSLT on the XML?

Comment: @Alohci I'm running it by linking the xsl file in line 2 of my XML, right under the declaration: `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="transform.xsl"?>` I get the same results when using the W3 TryIt editor, though.

Comment: @brohrig: People have tried to answer your question. If you are satisfied with one of the answers, you should accept it by clicking on the check-mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not really with XSLT, but with the result document from XSLT is serialised to a string.

You have specified the output method of "HTML" in the XSLT, which is used by the serialiser, but not everything you output is actually HTML. **Lines** is not an HTML element, and furthermore, because it has a namespace, all the child **br** elements are currently part of the namespace, and so these are probably not seen as HTML elements either.

When you remove the namespace, the **br** are then seen as HTML elements, and you get your expected behavior, because the serialisation process knows what to do with them.

One way to get around this, is to ensure the **br** elements are output without a namespace. Instead of using **xsl:for-each** for the lines, use **xsl:apply-templates**

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="o:lyrics/o:verse/o:lines" />
```

Then you would have templates matching **lines** and **br**. In particular, the template matching **br** would output the element without a namespace.

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:o="http://openlyrics.info/namespace/2009/song" exclude-result-prefixes="o">
   <xsl:output method="html"/>

   <xsl:template match="o:song">
      <html>
         <body>
            <h2>
               <xsl:value-of select="o:properties/o:titles/o:title"/>
               <br/>
            </h2>
            <h3>
               <xsl:for-each select="o:properties/o:authors/o:author">
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                  <br/>
               </xsl:for-each>
            </h3>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="o:lyrics/o:verse/o:lines"/>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="o:lines">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="o:br">
      <br/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should output the following

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Amazing Grace<br></h2>
<h3>John Newton<br></h3>
<lines xmlns="http://openlyrics.info/namespace/2009/song">
   Amazing grace, how sweet the sound<br xmlns="">
   That saved a wretch like me<br xmlns="">
   I once was lost, but now am found<br xmlns="">
   Was blind but now I see
</lines>
</body>
</html>
```

This should at least give you single line-breaks when viewed in a browser.